# rsync --include --exclude simple task doesn't work

Tags: shell, syntax, ssh, rsync, patternsyntaxexception

I would like to use rsync to download specific files from a server, here are the scheme of the directory:

```
. 
file1
fakeotherfolder
   filefile
   morefile
   morefakefolder
      file
file2
file3
mainfolder
   myfolder1
      folfile1
      folfile2
   myfolder2
      folfile1
      folfile2
   myfolder3
      folfile1
      folfile2
   myfolder4
      folfile1
      folfile2
```

Basically I would like to get ALL the files that are NOT in a `mainfolder/myfolder*` except the specific `mainfolder/myfolder2` for exemple.

**What I want at the end:**

```
 . 
file1
fakefolder
   filefile
   morefile
   morefakefolder
      file
file2
file3
mainfolder
   myfolder2
      folfile1
      folfile2
```

I tried rsync with the following options:

`rsync --include="*/mainfolder/myfolder2/*" --exclude="*/mainfolder/*"`

**but what I get is an empty mainfolder...**

```
 . 
file1
fakefolder
   filefile
   morefile
   morefakefolder
      file
file2
file3
mainfolder
```

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com would be better places for questions like this. SO is for programming questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What went wrong

```
rsync --include="*/mainfolder/myfolder2/*" --exclude="*/mainfolder/*"
```

1. The directive `--include="*/mainfolder/myfolder2/*"` tells `rsync` to include the files under directory `*/mainfolder/myfolder2/`.  You might think that it should implicitly tell it to include the directory `*/mainfolder/myfolder2/` but it doesn't.  It only includes the files under that directory.
2. The directive `--exclude="*/mainfolder/*"` tells it to exclude all files and directories under `*/mainfolder`.  This means that it excludes `*/mainfolder/myfolder2/`.  Because myfolder2 is excluded, the files under it will never be examined.

#### How to fix it

The solution is to explicitly include `mainfolder/myfolder2`:

```
rsync --include="mainfolder/myfolder2" --include="mainfolder/myfolder2/*" --exclude="mainfolder/*" src/ dest
```

The solution is to *explicitly* include `mainfolder/myfolder2`:

Note that `resync` interprets includes/excludes in the order in which they are stated.  Thus, it is important that `--include="mainfolder/myfolder2"` appears before `--exclude="mainfolder/*"`.  In sum, we need three directives and the exclude directive needs to be last:

1. `--include="mainfolder/myfolder2"`
2. `--include="mainfolder/myfolder2/*"`
3. `--exclude="mainfolder/*"`

Comment: I would add a slash before *mainfolder*, so that only the top directory is matched (may be unimportant in this case, but better in general).